# Building Elf Shared Library with MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, shared-libraries, elf

I'm trying to build an shared library on Windows with MinGW, follow this tutorial: 
[Building_elf_shared_libraries](http://nairobi-embedded.org/015_elf_shared_libraries.html#the-shared-object-name-soname)

I run this step:

```
$ gcc -fPICenter code here -c libfoo.c -o libfoo.o
$ gcc -Wall -O2 -shared -Wl,-soname,libfoo.so.1 -o libfoo.so.1.0.0 libfoo.o
```

When I get the .so I try to read it with *readelf* and get error:

```
$ readelf -h libfoo.so.1.0.0
readelf: Error: Not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start
```

Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: "This page presents a tutorial on the development and handling of shared libraries on a **GNU/Linux system** " <- the first line of that page

Comment: Do we have any solution to build elf shared lib on Windows?

Comment: @ChrisBritt He didn't ask for a library, he asked how to build a library. There's a pretty big difference between the two. PLEASE read the question before you write comments about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you did misunderstand something, MinGW is a port of gcc to use gcc to both target windows and run on windows natively (or if your host is linux, to target windows from linux). By default it will output files in PE format, not ELF. That's why your readelf call fails. With all that said I assume your trying to build a dynamically linked library and as such I'll provide a nice tutorial [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampledll) that should get you moving in the correct direction.

Comment: Your answer help me so much. Actually, I confuse Windows for Linux, I though I can use MinGW to build SOs in Windows env. After do some research, I find some toolchains can do that NDK, GCC ARM Embedded. Thanks.

Comment: @MocXi What is `SOs`?

Comment: "SOs" stand for shared libraries. For example: libpthread.so...